# How to use StartsWith in XmlNodeList foreach

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I have a xml file in which the members entries will be available. I have an xml like below,

**XML format**

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Email1>abc@xyz.com</Email1>
    <EmailType1>W</EmailType1>
    <Email2>xyz@xyz.com</Email2>
    <EmailType2>H</EmailType2>      // Email and EmailType can be upto `n` times.
  </User>
  <User>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Email1>lmn@xyz.com</Email1>
    <EmailType1>H</EmailType1>
    <Email2>bce@abc.com</Email2>
    <EmailType2>O</EmailType2>
  </User>
</Users>
```

I need a list of items from the above example xml. I am trying to use the **XmlNodeList** to loop through to form the list. I stuck here in extracting **Email** list. There is

**Code**

```
public List<ImportProp> ReturnItmsList(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
{
    List<ImportProp> ListImport = new List<ImportProp>();
    XmlNodeList parentNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Users/User");
    int cnt = 1;
    foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in parentNode)
    {
        ImportProp ppd = new ImportProp();
        ppd.BorrowId = (childrenNode["Id"] == null) ? "" : childrenNode["BorrowId"].InnerText;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
var result = childrenNode.SelectNodes("*")
                       .Cast<XmlNode>()
                       .Where(o => o.LocalName.StartsWith("EmailType"))
                       .Select(o => new 
                       {
                         email = o.PreviousSibling.InnerText,
                         emailType = o.InnerText
                       })
                       .ToList();
```

You can also use `starts-with()` in XPath :

```
var result = childrenNode.SelectNodes("*[starts-with(local-name(), 'EmailType')]")
                       .Cast<XmlNode>()
                       .Select(o => new 
                       {
                         email = o.PreviousSibling.InnerText,
                         emailType = o.InnerText
                       })
                       .ToList();
```